# C# - Extracting items from ItemClickEventArgs

Tags: c#

I have a UWP app that uses SemanticZoom. In zoomed in mode I have entered this in the xaml-code:
`ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick"`. Tapping an item in zoomed in mode takes me here:

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e){
{
     var item = e.ClickedItem;

     ...

}
```

Hovering over the item in Debug mode shows this:

item {Bookstore2Universal_10.BookSku}

Author        {Bookstore2Universal_10.Author}

AuthorName     "A"

Title          "Book1"

Question: How do I get hold of the Title? I have searched very hard to find a similar example but to no avail. I intentionally leave other details out because I don't think they are relevant. 
Hopefully someone out there has the answer.

Comment: `item` can be cast to whatever Type is bound to  your grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself (and a tip from a user who posted to me)

I made a cast of the right type:
BookSku item = (e.ClickedItem as BookSku)